# Firebase UI Phone Authentication not working on simulator

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

After working for more than a year, the Firebase UI Phone Authentication stopped working while appearing to still work on devices. The screen for entering the user's phone number appears but then crashes as in the screen and app becomes totally unresponsive. However, there is no crash detected in the console. The console repeats in seemingly random order these three similar messages:

Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}

Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated.}

Updating selectors after delegate removal failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process.}

And lastly I get this message in the console:

Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad; using 25873_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default

Here is the code calling the Firebase UI:

```
@objc func presentRegistration() {
    guard let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI() else { handleSignInError(); return }
    let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [FUIPhoneAuth(authUI: authUI)]
    authUI.delegate = self
    authUI.providers = providers
    guard let phoneProvider = authUI.providers.first as? FUIPhoneAuth else { handleSignInError(); return }
    phoneProvider.signIn(withPresenting: self, phoneNumber: "")
}
```

with this delegate function:

```
func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) {
    if let _ = error {
        present(message: "There was an error signing in. Please check that there is an active internet connection and that the number entered is correct. Then try again.")
    } else {
        self.loginUser()
    }
}
```

I tried updating my Firebase podfiles, but that didn't fix the problem. Googling the console messages didn't help. I tried deleting the app from the simulator, but that made no difference. Any suggestions for what to do?

***I've actually found it works on some simulators and not others. Seems like it should work on all or none. For example, it works on 11 but not 11 pro. Doesn't work on SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that going to the simulator's Device section and click "Erase All Content and Settings" fixes this problem. Not sure what the issue was that caused it, but this fixes it.